# RUBY: Why does open(ARGV.first) in a function not move to the next line in subsequent runs?

Tags: ruby, file-io

I am working through Exercise 20 of [Learn Ruby the Hard Way](https://learnrubythehardway.org/book/ex20.html), and am trying to make sense of the difference in output between defining the variable "current_file" and simply using open(ARGV.first):

Here is the input file test.txt:

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
```

Here is the beginning of the script:

```
input_file = ARGV.first

def print_a_line(f)
  puts "#{f.gets}"
end

current_file = open(input_file)
```

When I call the print_a_line with the declared variable:

```
print_a_line(current_file)
print_a_line(current_file)
print_a_line(current_file)
```

Then f.gets tracks to the new line each time:

```
This is line 1
This in line 2
This is line 3
```

However, if I call the function with ARGV.first:

```
print_a_line(open(ARGV.first))
print_a_line(open(ARGV.first))
print_a_line(open(ARGV.first))
```

Then f.gets does not track to the new line and remains on line 1:

```
This is line 1
This is line 1
This is line 1
```

And the same even with input_file:

```
print_a_line(open(input_file))
print_a_line(open(input_file))
print_a_line(open(input_file))
```

f.get still doesn't track to the next line:

```
This is line 1
This is line 1
This is line 1
```

Obviously, I would declare and use variables -- I understand the basics of writing neat, readable code.

My question is why does f.get track to the next line when the function is called with a declared variable and not track to the next line when called with the open(ARGV.first) or open(input_file)?

Why do I have to declare the variable again?

```
current_file = open(input_file)
```

Comment: `open(ARGV.first)` reopens the file each time. where as `current_file = open(input_file)` opens the file once and stores the file in its open state in the variable `current_file`

Comment: ^^ is this an answer? if so, why not leave it as an answer?

Comment: This has to do with mutable object. `open(ARGV.first)` is mutable because you can call `.gets` multiple times and get different results. But each time you run `open(ARGV.first)` you get a _fresh_ mutable object in the _initial state_.

Comment: Look at it this way: "get a new boyfriend; tell dad about him; tell dad about him; tell dad about him" is quite different from "get a new boyfriend and tell dad about him; get a new boyfriend and tell dad about him; get a new boyfriend and tell dad about him". Phrasing matters :)

Comment: How would you ever think that Ruby creates any connection between an IO object `a = open(input_file)` and `b = open(input_file)` so that when you had read up to line `n` in `a`, the next time you read from `b`, it reads from line `n + 1`? That does not make sense.